# Scrapy getting all pages hrefs from an array of startUrls

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

The problem I have is the following: I am trying to scrape a website that has multiple categories of products, and for each category of products, it has several pages with 24 products in each. I am able to get all starting urls, and scraping every page I am able to get the urls (endpoints, which I then make into full urls) of all pages.

I should say that not for every category I have product pages, and not every starting url is a category and thus it might not have the structure I am looking for. But most of them do.

My intent is: from all pages of all categories I want to extract the href of every product displayed in the page. And the code I have been using is the following one:

```
import scrapy 

class MySpider(scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider):
    name = 'myProj'
    with open('resultt.txt','r') as f:
        endurls = f.read()
        f.close()
    
    endurls= endurls.split(sep=' ')
    endurls = ['https://www.someurl.com'+url for url in endurls]
        
    start_urls = endurls
    
    def parse(self, response):
        with open('allpages.txt', 'a') as f:
            
            pages_in_category = response.xpath('//option/@value').getall()
            length = len(pages_in_category)
            pages_in_category = ['https://www.someurl.com'+page for page in pages_in_category]
            if length == 0:
                f.write(str(response.url))
            else:
                for page in pages_in_category:
                    f.write(page)
            f.close()
```

Through scrapy shell I am able to make it work, though not iteratively. The command I run in the terminal is then

```
scrapy runspider ScrapyCarr.py -s USER_AGENT='my-cool-project (http://example.com)'
```

Since I have not initialized a proper scrapy structure (I don't need that, it is a simple project for uni and I do not care much about the structure). Unfortunately the file in which I am trying to append my products urls remains empty, even if when inputting it through scrapy shell I see it working.

The output I am currently getting is the following

```
2020-10-15 12:51:56 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.someurl.com/market/fish/typefish/N-4minn0/c> (referer: None)
2020-10-15 12:51:57 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.someurl.com/market/medicines/typemed/N-i50owa/c> (referer: None)
2020-10-15 12:51:57 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.someurl.com/market/medicines/typemed/N-1l0cnr6/c> (referer: None)
2020-10-15 12:51:57 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.someurl.com/market/medicines/typemed/N-18isujc/c> (referer: None)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was initializing my class MySpider with a spider.CrawlSpider. The code works when using a class spider.Spider.
SOLVED